# Does the "sugar high" exist at all?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, children, sugar

I've heard numerous times that eating<sup>1</sup> a high quantity of sugar will give you a "sugar high" or "sugar buzz"

> The high one gets after consuming large amounts of sugar. Also called a "sugar rush." Sugar highs cause twitchiness, spasms, and hyper excitability. Sugar highs do not last very long, and leave a person feeling drained afterwards.
>   --[source](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sugar%20high)

Also, I've heard, that for the same reason, giving too much sugar to kids will make them hyperactive.

> Hyperactivity may be caused by learning disability, an unstable home life, food allergy, food additives, excessive sugar ingestion, heavy metal toxicity, or even the need for glasses.
>   --[source](http://www.liferesearchuniversal.com/hyperactivity.html)

This sounds like bogus to me. Is there any evidence on this claim, or is it just a urban myth?

---

<sup>1: Please assume non-diabetics</sup>

Comment: Is is defined anywhere how high `high quantity` is? I once consumed around 750 g of sugar to test the myth out and none of the described events happened to me (there were problems related with consuming such amount of water absorbing crystals though, so I don't recommend it to anyone).

Comment: I think you'd have to separate the scope of the inquiry into two: non-diabetics and diabetics.  My guess would be the energy level of diabetics would definitely affected by sugar, whereas the energy level of a non-diabetic would remain pretty much the same.  You also have to limit the amount, as anything in a large amount will have some sort of effect.  For example, drinking too much water can kill you, etc.  I doubt anyone can eat a cup of sugar without feeling *some* effect, but I don't think a tiny piece of candy has any effect other than perhaps a mental one.

Comment: The scope is intended for the general public - the claim does not require the in-taker to be diabetic.

Comment: I was always under the impression that the "high" was describing the comparison to the "low" that follows when the body produces insulin to reduce the high sugar levels. Is there any info on that facet?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Here](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/answer-sheet/guest-bloggers/willingham-how-sugar-really-af.html) is a Washington Post article that also says "NO":

> A stronger type of study is one in
>   which no one--the kids, the parents,
>   or the experimenter--knows whether the
>   snack the child ate was sweetened with
>   sugar or with aspartame. More than [a
>   dozen such studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8747098?dopt=Abstract) have been
>   conducted, and they show that **sugar
>   does not cause hyperactive behavior or
>   behavior problems**, even when the
>   researchers make a point of testing
>   kids whose parents say they are
>   sensitive to sugar.

...

> Sugar has also been tested for its
>   impact on kids diagnosed with ADHD.
>   Again, there seems to be [no effect](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199402033300511).

...

> **[One interesting study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7963081?dopt=Abstract) examined
>   the effect of parental expectation**.
>   Thirty-five boys (aged 5 to 7) who
>   were reported by their mothers to be
>   sugar sensitive were given a drink
>   sweetened with aspartame. **Half of the
>   moms were told that the drink had a
>   lot of sugar in it, and half were told
>   it had none**. Mothers and sons then
>   interacted on several tasks (e.g.,
>   building a Lego house together). **Moms
>   who were told their children had had
>   sugar later rated their sons’ behavior
>   during this interaction as more
>   hyperactive**.

The bottom line:

> **There’s pretty good evidence that
>   there is *not* a physiological effect of
>   sugary snacks on kids’ behavior**, and
>   some of parent’s perception of an
>   effect is probably just
>   that--perception. But there could also
>   be a psychological effect whereby
>   sugary snacks are associated with
>   other factors such as a less regulated
>   atmosphere or kids’ perception of a
>   less well regulated atmosphere.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: I've grown up in Eastern Europe and nobody there has ever heard of a sugar rush or a sugar high. It's always puzzled me as I've never experienced anything like it myself. Now I know. Another bogus claim debunked. Thanks!

Comment: Other series of anecdotes: none of the people I know who had to do an [oral glucose tolerance test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose_tolerance_test) where you get 75 g glucose (in 300 ml water) within 5 min. felt high... In case someone wants to do a study, there are plenty of candiates to recruit from these tests...

Answer (score 12):

[No says CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/HEALTH/children/9911/22/diet.sugar.myth.kids.wmd/). The amount of sugar that you *tell* the parent their child took [does affect their perception](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7963081) of the child's activity level though.